Recode values before reaching a certain value and not after in struct field matlab
I have a struct called "x". x has several fields within it. One of these is known as "type" (i.e., x.type). type is a character field. Below is an example of what the data in x.type looks like:
'boundary'
'E  3'
'E  5'
'E  3'
'E  5'
'E  3'
'E  5'
'E 24'
'E 40'
'E 65'
'boundary'
'E 48'
'E132'
'E 48'
'E132'
'E 48'
'E130'
'E 48'
'E130'

I want to rename all the values before 'E 48' with 'E999' and to leave 'boundary' the values after 'E 48' as they are.
I'm mostly an R user, so not too sure how to do this in Matlab.
Any tips would be appreciated!

A for loop would be the most straightforward answer. Of course you could vectorize this, but it would be a lot less readable and most likely not any faster.

What variable type actually is that field? A cell array of chars? A "character field" isn't a variable type in MATLAB, but given the lines are different lengths I assume it's not a character array. You could just do a for loop and break when you get to the entry you want to stop replacing things at. Or use strcmp to find the E 48 line and replace everything before then...

Hi both. Apologies for my mistype - yes, this seems to be a cell array of chars. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give this a go.

Is x actually a struct array, i.e. you have x(0).type which equals 'boundary', x(1).type equals 'E  3' etc? In that case the data in each field is a character vector. MATLAB string stuff is confusing because proper strings and string arrays were only introduced in R2016b - before that you only had character vectors and arrays, but people who learned MATLAB before then tend to call those 'strings'. As a loop-phobe I'd like to propose a no-loop answer just because, but need to know exactly what the data type is first.

Hi @nekomatic. Yes. x is a struct array. If I type x(0).type then I get 'boundary'. Thank you for explaining the terminology for me :) It's helpful. I'd be very open to a no-loop answer also!

Since you asked for a no-loop solution,
This shoves all of the x.type values in a cell array and then creates a logical array to index it. The logical array puts non-zero values at the indices starting with the first occurrence of 'E 48' through the end of the array, and at indices where the type is 'boundary', then we negate the logical array. Values at the 1 indices are set to 'E999' and the cell array is put back into x.type.
type_cell = {x.type};
type_cell(~(cumsum(strcmp(type_cell,'E 48'))|strcmp(type_cell,'boundary'))) = 'E999';
[x.type]= type_cell{:};


I gave up trying to write a no-loop answer as I couldn't figure out how to assign back to specific elements of the structure array (answers welcome!).
I would use:
LastToReplace = find(strcmp({x.type}, 'E 48'), 1) - 1;
for ele = 1:LastToReplace
    if ~strcmp(x(ele).type, 'boundary')
        x(ele).type = 'E999'; 
    end
end

The syntax {x.type} returns the contents of the type field of the elements of struct x as a cell array. strcmp with a cell array and a character vector returns a logical vector recording whether each cell element was a match; and find(A, 1) returns the index of the first nonzero element of A.
